# debugging the infinite loop after authorization with javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, authorization, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

As per usual, FB has me pulling out my hair.

I've been able to test my app in IE9, but when using Firefox, after a user authorizes the canvas app it goes into a redirect loop, adding state and code variables to the URL.

I'm using the javascript and php sdk with this code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $app_id,
'secret' => $application_secret,
'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!($user))
{
echo"<script> top.location.href='" . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' 
=> $fbconfig['appBaseUrl'],
'scope' => 'manage_notifications,publish_stream,publish_actions'
)) . "'</script>";
exit();
}
```

I read about adding this:
if (window.location.hash =='#*=*') window.location.hash=''; but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: make sure that you are redirecting to correct URL's. i.e. if user is using http then your redirect URL uses http and same for https.

Comment: @Imran That's not the issue. Anyway, after Oct. 1st all apps have to be https as per Facebook's roadmap.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? Did the solution below work for you?

Comment: No, for some reason it started redirecting to the app's page on my server, not facebook. Gonna grab the latest sdk and start from scratch again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my latest app.
Solved it by using the code above in the < head > section.
Don't forget to upgrade your PHP SDK to the latest version.

```
<?
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'YYY',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
  ));
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Been away for a bit. Will look at this solution ASAP. Thanks.